# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getInstalledApps on channel installed_apps)

Tags: flutter, dart, installed-applications

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getInstalledApps on channel installed_apps)
```

`E/flutter ( 4648): <asynchronous suspension>`

These errors are occured when i try to get the list of installed apps from **installed_apps** package from flutter.

This is my code:

```
List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps();
```

Comment: Can you include more about the snippet and package you are using

Comment: Only Android is supported - are you trying this on a different platform?

Comment: try restarting the project